# Details on Demand

Tags: tibco, spotfire

Is there a way to configure details on demand for **a page** completely in one go.

i have multiple visuals with different markings in a page. all visuals in a  page have same data table. i dont need all of the columns in Details on Demand. I have to select and order columns from the list of columns in Details on demand.

it seems like i have to configure it **separately for each visuals** . **Is there a way to do it in one time for all visuals in a page.** its a much time consuming work as i have 100+ columns to select and order separately for each visuals in a 24 tab spotfire file

much appreciated

Comment: You could duplicate the page and then just remove all your charts, leaving your Details on Demand... otherwise I don't think there is a way.

Comment: So can i put all charts back after that in the page with Details on Demand? Will DoD work after that for all charts?

Comment: Should remain the same but just give it a try. If it doesn't work just delete the page. No harm done

Comment: Sorry, Its not working